# How to delay coping file for 1s after getting event?

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, download

I am downloading files from some third-party server, we have no way to get download done event (at least from the server) for each file. There are around 20 files, as soon as individual file gets downloaded, we need to copy to some other location (this needs to be as fast as possible).

To check if any new file arrived I am using `ReadDirectoryChanges` API.

```
while (ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            hDir, /* handle to directory */
            &buffer, /* read results buffer */
            sizeof(buffer), /* length of buffer */
            TRUE, /* monitoring option */
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            &bytesReturned, /* bytes returned */
            NULL, /* overlapped buffer */
            NULL)) /* completion routine */

{
   //do file copy after download completes
}
```

Now the problem is we are not sure when download completes. We get multiple events from `ReadDirectoryChanges`, everytime something is written to file we get an event.

**Is there any way to know that download is completed for that particular file for which we are getting an event?**

As a workaround, we have decided to wait for 1s before start copying. But in that one second, if I get another notification, I need to wait for another 1s.

We will initiate file copying in the separate thread and multiple file copy can happen in parallel.

Now which data structure I can use to track 1 second, and if another event occurs in between it should reinitiate with 1s?  Initially, I thought of priority queue, but we need to check every 10ms that some timeout happened or not. Also, there will be a problem if multiple elements get added to the priority queue, it may lead to recopying file.

Maybe my way of dealing this problem is completely absurd. I am open to a better approach.

Comment: maybe you can check the file lock state to determine if the download finish.
for delay maybe something like WaitableTimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly after you received a `FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED` event for a file, try to open the file, denying shared writing, but allow shared reading. As long as another process has the file open for writing, you won't be able to open it, so wait for the next event.